# How to use in indexOf with a List out of int[][]?

Tags: java, arraylist, multidimensional-array, contains, indexof

This is the method I created that works. I used Arrays.deepEquals. It checks if a int[][] is inside a ArrayList out of int[][]. Thank you Thomas, for giving the solution!

```
public boolean contains(int[][]matrix1, List<int[][]> matrice){
boolean contains = false;
  for(int[][] m : matrice){
    if(Arrays.deepEquals(m, matrix)){
        contains = true;
        index = matrice.indexOf(m);
    }
  }
  return contains;
}
```

I have the following code. I want to get the index from the matrice that has the same value as matrix. I think it doesn't work because I'm checking for references and not values. I just can't figure out how it should be done.

```
    List<int[2][2]> matrice = new ArrayList<int[][]>();
    int[][] matrix = new int[2][2]
    public void testMethod(){
      // here matrix gets a value
      matrix = {{1,4}{3,2}};
      //Here List matrice gets filled with different matrice (4x)
       ...
     //add a copy of matrix to matrice
      matrice.add(copy2dArray(matrix));
      int index = matrice.indexOf(matrix);
      System.out.println("matrix ->"Arrays.deepToString(matrix));
      System.out.println("matrice[4] ->"Arrays.deepToString(matrice[4]));
      System.out.println("index = "+index);
      System.out.println(matrice.contains(matrix));
    }

        private int[][] copy2dArray(int[][] original){
            int[][] copy = new int[original.length][];
            for(int i = 0; i < original.length; i++){
                copy[i] = Arrays.copyOf(original[i], original[i].length);
            }
            return copy;
        }
```

OUTPUT:

```
matrix -> [[1,4],[3,2]]
matrice[4] -> [[1,4],[3,2]]
index = -1
false
```

OUTPUT SHOULD BE:

```
matrix -> [[1,4],[3,2]]
matrice[4] -> [[1,4],[3,2]]
index = 4
true
```

Comment: Why should the index be 4 in your example?

Comment: Just as an example it would be the 5th matrix added to matrice List. So that would make it index 4. As long as it gives the right index back, that has the same value as matrix. you can see in the output that matrice[4] == index

Comment: `copy2dArray` probably doesn't return the exact same Object, and `indexOf` will search for the `matrix` object , not a copy (as the default `equals` method for arrays is `array1 == array2` ) .

Comment: Yes I was thinking the same, but do you know how I can fix this? I do need  to keep using an ArrayList.

Comment: I got an awnser selected as the right one, doesnt that make it a proper awnser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `ArrayList.indexOf()` (as do most other implementations) iterate over the elements and call `equals()` on each until one matches. The index of that is then returned, which in your example should be 0 (not 4).

However, arrays don't define their own `equals()` implementation and thus the default implementation defined in `Object` is used, which only returns true if the arrays are the *exact same instances* (which due to you copying the array they are not).

To fix that you could use a wrapper that contains the array and implements `equals()` (and `hashCode()`) appropriately. That "wrapper" could be called `Matrix` and probably would also result in a better design anyways ;)

Example:

```
class Matrix {
  int[][] theCells;

  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    //compare the indivual arrays, e.g. by using `Arrays.deepEquals()`, 
    //which takes care of multidimensional arrays
  }
}

List<Matrix> matrices = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Can I get the index then aswell?

Comment: @user2173361 yes, with a correct implementation of equals()  you'll then get the index of the matrix (if it is in the list).